# ViewData in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, viewdata

I have this code in the view:

```
foreach (var item in someList)
{
    foreach (var item1 in item)
    {
            <tr >
                 <td class="clickableCell" id='@item1.idE'>@item1.name</td>
                 <td class="clickableCell"id='@item1.idE'>@ViewData["allroles"]</td>
            </tr> 
    }
}
```

`ViewData["allroles"]` is a list of elements which contain idE and one string. How can I - for the second `td`, get the only the string, without another `foreach`?

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to it's correct type and then use the indexing to get your wanted value.

Should be something like this (where i is the index of your current row):

```
@((Dictionary<IDE, string>)ViewData["allroles"])[i].value
```